# Zend Framework php.ini include path

Tags: php, zend-framework, include

so, I'm trying to get Zend Framework running, which has terribly vague instructions.

It simply says, put the Zend folder in the directory, and add it to your `include_path` in `php.ini`.

So, this is my include path:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/tuner/public_html/market/Zend_1.12.3/library"
```

This is the section that should be including Zend, I have double checked the path:

```
/home/tuner/public_html/market/Zend_1.12.3/library
```

However, when I try to include a Zend class, I am still getting errors as though it is not included properly.

This is what is causing the error:

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale('en_CA');
Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale);
```

What am I doing wrong when including the framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you get an error when you try and include ZF class, but nowhere in the code you posted are you including a class (e.g. `require_once 'Zend/Locale.php';`). If you want ZF classes to be automatically included when you try and use them (which is the recommended approach), you need to [setup the autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.autoloading.usage.html). For ZF1, add the following somewhere above your existing code:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

ZF classes will then be automatically required in on demand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which docs you got the code snippet from, but you are mixing up ZF1 and ZF2. The part with Zend_Locale and Zend_Registry are ZF1 components, so this is clearly not going to work with the ZF2 library installed.

Comment: Alright, I uploaded ZF 1.12.3 and tried it with that, same issue still.